# Get whole text before the cursor

Tags: android, android-input-method

I need get whole text string before the cursor in my InputMethod class. getTextBeforeCursor() gets only "n" characters, but I don't know text's length.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440269/better-way-to-get-all-the-text-in-an-edittext-from-an-inputconnection) question/answer.  I recommend the `CharSequence currentText = inputConnection.getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(), 0).text;` solution, which gives you the text's length.

Comment: How you got the whole text from Microsoft's all apps? Bcz I have a facing an issue they only gave us a limited text.

Answer (score 2):

See this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html#getTextBeforeCursor%28int,%20int%29/%20%22). It seems that you can do this:

```
getCurrentInputConnection().getTextBeforeCursor(100, 0);
```

or some other large number since it only takes the text from the input - not all the 'n' characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.This should work.

```
//get the input connection first
InputConnection iconn = getCurrentInputConnection();
//get the total text first.
String full_text=iconn.getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(),0).text.toString();
//get whole text before the cursor
String before_text=iconn.getTextBeforeCursor(full_text.length(),0).toString();
```

Comment: this is not working properly in all ms's apps like only gave limited text.

Answer (score 0):

As was said above you can use getTextBeforeCursor() with large number. If it return string with same length, you can try get bigger one. But be careful, some applications, like email app from Samsung return whole length string! Even if you type 1 character.