# Better way to get all the text in an EditText from an InputConnection?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

I've written an IME (InputMethodService) and I need to get all the text from the EditText it is editing. I know one way:

```
InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
inputConnection.append(inputConnection.getTextBeforeCursor(9999, 0))
.append(inputConnection.getTextAfterCursor(9999, 0));
```

It works, but it seems pretty stupid and clunky. However there is no such method `InputConnection.getText()`.

Is there a better way?

P.S. I cannot access the EditText from my IME because it belongs to the parent app so please don't tell me to use EditText.getText(), unless you know a way to get the EditText!

Comment: Also, just to note, `getTextBeforeCursor` and `getTextAfterCursor` do not include the selected text (if there is a selection).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is also another way to do it:

```
inputConnection.performContextMenuAction(android.R.id.selectAll);
CharSequence sData =  inputConnection.getSelectedText(0);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that method is not available in v2.1 (which I'm still using), but thank you anyway and I up-voted because it is still a correct answer.

Comment: Did someone try that in Marshmallow? Because it didn't work here. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

My solution is to use getExtractedText(). I am not sure if this has some limitations, but has worked for me so far.

```
CharSequence currentText = inputConnection.getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(), 0).text;
```

Comment: Seems this not working anymore in Marshmallow 6 and 6.0.1, I tested it many times and I got some users confirm that.

Comment: It's not working properly in some application like I have faced an issue in Ms Word app. In Ms Word, I didn't get a whole text. Have you found any solution for that?

Comment: @MohammadAlBanna & Kinamand have u found any solution guy?

Comment: @PravinSuthar Have you found any solution ? If yes Can you please paste it here?. I need it.

Comment: @ChiragPrajapati not yet bro.

Comment: @PravinSuthar Let me please know about how you have handled it in your app?

Comment: @ChiragPrajapati I don't have any solution for this if you have plz share with me.